# Mysql stored procedure creation gets 2014 error

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Trying to create my first stored procedure, I have researched extensively and could not find a way to input the code via phpMyAdmin so downloaded MYSQL Workbench 6.0 and put my script in that way- but it throws a `2014 error (Commands out of sync, you cannot run this command now)`. However I notice that Workbench seems to create two lines - the first says running and the second the error.

The routine is to update three tables and insert into another when a contract is issued. Contracts are made up of bundles and they in turn consist of items which relate to specific problems in another table.

Is it my code or should I include some clearing command at the end and if so what should that be? The procedure input is a contract id, user id and their IP address (for logging).

In PHP when, eventually, using a CALL how would I clear results, as I keep seeing Stackoverflow 2014 answers where second calls fail? Also how can I get this onto an ubuntu server either via phpMyAdmin or if with putty where should I ftp the sql script to?

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ContrctAwardStatusLog;

CREATE PROCEDURE ContrctAwardStatusLog( IN c_Id INT(8), IN u_Id INT(11), IN u_Ip varchar(20) )
BEGIN
  Block1: BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE b_id INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE citm_id INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE r_id INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE c_1 CURSOR FOR SELECT bundle_id FROM bundles WHERE  contract_id = c_Id;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN c_1;
    REPEAT
      FETCH c_1 INTO b_id ;

      Block2: BEGIN
        DECLARE done2 INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE c_2 CURSOR FOR SELECT contitem_id, issue_id FROM c_items WHERE bundle_id= b_id;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done2 = 1;

        OPEN c_2;
        REPEAT
          FETCH c_2 INTO citm_id r_id;
          INSERT INTO track_status (rowid, WStatusBy, WStatus, WStatusWhen) VALUES(r_id, u_Id, 13,NOW());
          UPDATE h_issues SET WStatus='13' WHERE RowID = r_id;
          UPDATE c_items SET act_state='13' WHERE contitem_id=citm_id;

          UNTIL done2
        END REPEAT;
        CLOSE c_2;
      END Block2;

      UPDATE bundles SET bundle_stat = '13' WHERE bundle_id = b_id;
      UNTIL done
    END REPEAT;

    CLOSE c_1;
  END Block1;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally sorted this myself.

I needed to put the DROP ..if exists BEFORE the DELIMITER Setting and there was a syntax error in  the FETCH after OPEN c_2. It was missing a comma separator.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ContrctAwardStatusLog;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE ContrctAwardStatusLog( IN c_Id INT(8), IN u_Id INT(11), IN u_Ip varchar(20) )
BEGIN
  Block1: BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE b_id INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE citm_id INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE r_id INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE c_1 CURSOR FOR SELECT bundle_id FROM bundles WHERE  contract_id = c_Id;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN c_1;
    REPEAT
      FETCH c_1 INTO b_id ;

      Block2: BEGIN
        DECLARE done2 INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE c_2 CURSOR FOR SELECT contitem_id, issue_id FROM c_items WHERE bundle_id= b_id;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done2 = 1;

        OPEN c_2;
        REPEAT
          FETCH c_2 INTO citm_id, r_id;
          INSERT INTO track_status (rowid, WStatusBy, WStatus, WStatusWhen) VALUES(r_id, u_Id, 13,NOW());
          UPDATE h_issues SET WStatus='13' WHERE RowID = r_id;
          UPDATE c_items SET act_state='13' WHERE contitem_id=citm_id;

          UNTIL done2
        END REPEAT;
        CLOSE c_2;
      END Block2;

      UPDATE bundles SET bundle_stat = '13' WHERE bundle_id = b_id;
      UNTIL done
    END REPEAT;

    CLOSE c_1;
  END Block1;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `DROP ..` statement can also be there after defining new `delimiter`. But to force the drop be executed early, you should have used new delimiter to close the drop statement.

Comment: I am deleting my answer as it really did not pick the statement that caused the error.